# An interesting question about perfect squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

Find all the values of $n$ such that $n(n-101) $ is a complete square.

My attempt,

$n(n-101) = t^2$ (say)
This implies 
$(2n-101)^2=101^2+(2t)^2$  by completing square,
Now i applied Fibonacci's algorithm to find Pythagorean triples to get 
$n=2551$ and $t=5100$.
But how can I find all solutions if some more solutions exist. Kindly help.

Comment: $n=2551 \rightarrow 2551(2551 - 101) = 6249950 = 2^{1} + 5^{2} + 7^{2} + 2551^{1}$ is not a square.

Comment: Sorry I have definitely miscalculated

Comment: But one can use the algorithm to get a valid solution

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2152757/determine-all-integer-values-for-which-2-9-14-is-a-perfect-squar

Answer (score 3):

$$\gcd(n,n-101)=\gcd(n,101)$$
Now either $\gcd(n,101)=1\lor \gcd(n,101)=101$ lets assume that
$$\gcd(n,101)=1$$
Then both $n$ and $n-101$ are perfect squares so $n=t^2$ and $n-101=k^2$ so $t^2-k^2=(t-k)(t+k)=101$ since $101$ is prime $t+k=101$ and $t-k=1$ so $t=51$ and $k=50$ so one solution is $n=51^2$.

Now if $\gcd(n,101)=101$ then $n=101m$ I'll let you finish this case if you need more help feel free to tell me in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Using $x$ so as not to confuse other math, if $x(x-101)=x^2-101x$ can be seen as though it were $C^2-B^2=A^2$,

Then $\quad C=m^2+n^2=\sqrt{x^2}=x\quad and \quad B=2mn=\sqrt{101x}$

So we have a term $B$ and if we factor for n, we get

$$n=\frac{\sqrt{101x}}{2m}$$
 we can see that $x$ must be the product of $101$ and $4$ and another number which must equal to or a multiple of $m^2$ if n is to be an integer. Let us begin with $x=1616$ and $m=2$ (because $m<2$ yields a trivial Pythagorean triple.

$$n=\frac{\sqrt{101*1616}}{2*2}=\frac{\sqrt{163216}}{4}=\frac{404}{4}=101$$
But then we get $f(2,101)=(-10197,404,10205)$ which is valid but undesirable. If we reverse $m$ and $n$ we get $f(101,2)=(10197,404,10205).$ 
If we try $m=102\implies x=41208$, we get $f(102,100)=(404,20400,20404).$

I've now spent too long on this and cannot see my errors anymore but I hope this approach might be helpful if you can work the math properly.